# Need code sample to create a report that counts unique event to one customer on multiple days

Tags: trigger, reporting, class, event, code

I am trying to create a unique customer touches report. Meaning if I create an event on a customer site 5 times on a particular day, and 2 events for the same customer on a different day, we could have a summary that tells us that this customer was touched on 2 unique days.

I am looking for an apex code sample that can accomplish this task.

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without Apex code. You can create an report for Activities with Accounts, make the report type "Summary", and filter by Account Name and Activity Date.